How to Show Colours
I'm very new to Blender.
I purchased a Rocket Launcher from Render Hub. M202 RL
It came with Blender 4.1 file. I can load it in but I don't have a clue how to show the Colours or Textures or Whatever they are called. It has the nodes set up and TGA files.


I would like to export it to DAZ, complete with colours showing, so it displays correctly in DAZ, if possible.

Have you tried File > External Data > Find Missing Files ... from the main menu? Navigate to the M202_Flash_main_textures folder (or subfolder). Blender will try to find the image textues there.
